# Is it possible to play AVQueuePlayer in reverse order?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avqueueplayer

I am using AVQueuePlayer and it is working fine. 
My problem now is that I have a back button. If I press the button, previous video needs to be played. Is there any way for that?

Thanks.

Comment: i think that is not possible .,

Comment: Please Refer the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176699/skip-to-previous-avplayeritem-on-avqueueplayer-play-selected-item-from-queue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176699/skip-to-previous-avplayeritem-on-avqueueplayer-play-selected-item-from-queue