# Move to Previous AVPlayerItem AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios5, avplayer, avqueueplayer

Trying to allow user to skip backwards in AVQueuePlayer while preserving the original AVQueuePlayer collection. For instance, user hits back button twice and resumes listening from previous position. Referring to this [Skip to Previous AVPlayerItem on AVQueuePlayer / Play selected Item from queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176699/skip-to-previous-avplayeritem-on-avqueueplayer-play-selected-item-from-queue) - appears to dump all items from queue and play only a specified item. Without having to re-initialize/populate queue every time, is there a way to skip back and have queue resume its flow to completion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No. [Apple's documentation explains](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that when advancing to the next item, `AVQueuePlayer` removes the current item from the queue. Given there's only `-insertItem:afterItem:`, there's no way of re-inserting items before the current item without dumping and rebuilding the queue.

Comment: It should also be noted that `removeAllItems` is quite bugged. When doing so and inserting two new items it will attempt to play the first one but it will go straight to the second one. Behavior observed through KVO currentItem, iOS 6.0.2.