# Play nth item of AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avqueueplayer

I have an instance of `AVQueuePlayer` and I've initialised it with a collection of videos using `AVPlayerItem` (let's say I have 10 items), On a button event, I need to play the item of nth index from the collection.

I've used `- (void)replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:(AVPlayerItem *)item` but it replaces the current playing item with the passed `AVPlayerItem`.

I need to play nth `AVPlayerItem` of the `AVQueuePlayer`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ideas, not tested:

A. Advancing

```
NSUInteger indexToPlay = …
AVPlayerItem *currentItem = [queuePlayer currentItem];
NSUInteger currentIndex = [[queuePlayer items] indexOfObject:currentItem];
for (;currentIndex<indexToPlay; currentIndex++)
{
  [queuePlayer advanceToNextItem];
}
```

B. Calculating the time

Get the duration using `-duration` (`AVPlayerItem`) of all videos from the beginning of the queue up to (but not including) the nth video and go to the resulting time with 
`-seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:`.

I think that you should have no problem with tolerance and decoding delay, because the seemed time is the beginning of a video.

Comment: Tried B option, but it results in crash as the AVPlayerItem.duration results in NAN coz, its status is not ready yet and hence the player doesn't seek to time and the application crashes. Did tried to observe the status of the current item and then calculate the seek time,but its not working either.

Comment: Option A is bang on. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: this solution will work if the play item is in next of current how about if the item that we want to play is in back ?

Comment: @FadiAbuzant you might be better off searching for other answers related to playing previous item. There are many here on SO, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971839/better-way-to-do-skip-to-previous-with-avqueueplayer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176699/skip-to-previous-avplayeritem-on-avqueueplayer-play-selected-item-from-queue/12209586)

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)playAudioAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    [player removeAllItems];
    for (int i = index; i <playerItems.count; i ++) {
        AVPlayerItem* obj = [playerItems objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([player canInsertItem:obj afterItem:nil]) {
        [obj seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [player insertItem:obj afterItem:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

playerItems is the NSMutableArray(NSArray) where you store your AVPlayerItems.

Comment: Updating the AVQueuePlayers's content also helps in if the user taps the previous items, so thanks :)