# How to convert ++ or -- in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I have the following code I am trying to convert to Swift 3 and am getting this weird error "Cannot convert value of type Bool to expected argument type Int". The issue arises when I get rid of the "++". I am also linking to the stack overflow question I want to fully convert. Thanks! Here is the previous code and the code I tried to convert to:

Previous code

```
func previousTrack() {
if currentTrack-- < 0 {
    currentTrack = (playerItems.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (playerItems.count - 1)
} else {
    currentTrack--
}

playTrack()
```

}

Converted code

```
@IBAction func didTapPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentTrack += 1 < 0 {  // Issue occurs here
        currentTrack = (urlPlayerItems.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (urlPlayerItems.count - 1)
    } else {
        currentTrack -= 1
    }

    playTrack()

}
```

[Original question I want to convert to Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971839/better-way-to-do-skip-to-previous-with-avqueueplayer)

EDIT:

```
@IBAction func didTapPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (currentTrack - 1) <= 0 {
        currentTrack = (urlPlayerItems.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (urlPlayerItems.count - 1)
    } else {
        currentTrack -= 1
    }

    playTrack()

}



@IBAction func didTapNextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (currentTrack + 1) >= urlPlayerItems.count {
        currentTrack = 0
    } else {
        currentTrack += 1
    }

    playTrack()
}
```

Comment: Spend an extra line, first decrement than check < 0.

Comment: that'd be my recommendation too

Comment: Why are you replacing the old `--` with `+=` ? Why not `-=` ?

Comment: @LeoDabus - that's not a duplicate. The question isn't asking about how to replace `++`. The question is about using `+=` in an `if` statement comparison.

Comment: @rmaddy feel free to reopen if you would like to. Hamish also voted for it to be closed

Comment: Ther original code is too complicated.  You need only `let previous = (currentTrack - 1 + playerItems.count) % playerItems.count` and `let next = (currentTrack + 1) % playerItems.count`.

Comment: Hey I added a 'edited' version to my question! Please add code snipped showing the correct way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I just edited my original answer to include a Swift 3 version.  If anyone sees any issues, feel free to comment or edit. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35015898/2415822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want IMHO

```
@IBAction func didTapPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    currentTrack -= 1
    if currentTrack < 0 {
        currentTrack = (urlPlayerItems.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (urlPlayerItems.count - 1)
    }

    playTrack()
}
```

Correct replacing of POSTFIX as you have it (useless)

```
@IBAction func didTapPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentTrack < 0 {
        currentTrack -= 1
        currentTrack = (urlPlayerItems.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (urlPlayerItems.count - 1)
    }

    playTrack()
}
```

Comment: The original code used post decrement, so `if currentTrack < 0` without decrementing first.

Comment: IMHO this isn't what he wants but didn't see it. I edited my answer though

Comment: Please check my edited version! If possible add sample code showing me what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help!